# How do i fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Every time I run the code my code aimed at building a weak Ai platform I receive a **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'**, and I have totally no clue why as it works fine in a tutorial i am following.can someone please walk me through fixing this as I am fairly new to python. Thanks

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import pythoncom

print("Initializing Bot")

MASTER = "Bob"

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

    if hour>=0 and hour <12:
        speak("Good Morning" + MASTER)

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon" + MASTER)
    else:
        speak("Good Evening" + MASTER)


    speak("How may I assist you?")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try :
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")

speak("Initializing bot...")
wishMe()
    query = takeCommand()

#Logic

if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
    speak('Searching wikipedia...')
    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences =2)
    print(results)
    speak(results)


if 'open youtube' in query.lower():
    webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

Alternatively the microphone also does not pick up an input, any ideas on why this is also the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because the variable `query` is sometimes `None`. And you are applying `.lower()` function on it which only works on `str` type objects.

You can control this by putting your code inside a `if` loop which runs only when there's a string in query variable. Like this maybe:

```
wishMe()
query = takeCommand()

#Logic

if query:
    if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
        speak('Searching wikipedia...')
        query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences =2)
        print(results)
        speak(results)


    if 'open youtube' in query.lower():
        webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

Comment: thank you but how do i fix the fact that the mic does not pick up an input?

Answer (score 0):

You functions are not returning anything. So for example:

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try :
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
    return query
```

*Don't forget to mark my answer accepted if it helped you*

Comment: You need to add return query in your function as I mentioned and in your logic add "if query:" , like how Mayank Porwal said

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to help you, but I do not have the context from what are you trying to do but I will give you an example:

```
wishMe()
query = takeCommand()

#Logic

if query:
# an then you can check your condition
query.lower()
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but that error has already been corrected by a previous member.However, there is still one more problem if you could possibly help me with. Every time i run the code my mic does not pick up an input which it should turn into speech to text as part of the speech recognition system i have integrated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return type of `takeCommand` function... then
`query=takeCommand`
function can work otherwise it can back you a error just nonetype...
so, add `return query` in `takeCommand` function after try and except

I hope it will help you

Thanks